# getting null instead of elements in list for R program

Tags: r

So i am trying to make a program that computes the Collatz conjecture, throws each number into a vector, and throws the vectors into a list but when i go to call the elements(L[[17][4] should give 13) of the list i get null.Here is what i have so far:

```
hailstone<-function(num){
p=0
v<-c()
v<-c(v,num)
while(num>1) {
  
  if(num%%2==1){
    
    num=num*3+1
  }else{
    num=num/2
  }
  p=p+1
  v<-c(v,num)
}



L <- vector("list", 100)
for (num in 1:100) {
  L[num]<- v
  
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to access `L`? If you're trying to access it outside `hailsone()`, then `L` is null, as it's only declared inside the function.

Comment: Then you're getting the expected result. The environment of the console does not know `L` exists. L only exists in the environment inside the function.

Comment: You are assigning 100 times the same vector `v`. Each member of list `L` will be equal to `v`.

Comment: thanks yall i updated my code for L to be equal to hailstone and added a return statement to the hailstone function and that fixed everything

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten your code to put as much inside the function as possible and included an explicit return statement:

```
hailstone <- function(num1, num2) {
  p <- 0
  v <- c()
  v <- c(v, num1)
  
  while (num1 > 1) {
    if (num1 %% 2 == 1) {
      num1 <- num1 * 3 + 1
    } else {
      num1 <- num1 / 2
    }
    p <- p + 1
    v <- c(v, num1)
  }
  L <- vector("list", 100)
  for (i in 1:100) {
    L[[i]] <- v
  }
  return(L[[num1]][num2])
}
```

Then, you can just call the function with two parameters.

```
hailstone(17, 4)
# > hailstone(17, 4)
# [1] 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of producing the Collatz sequences up to given `num`.

In the first, a function `haillist` calls `hailstone` passing it every integer from 1 to `num` and returns a Collatz sequences list.

```r
hailstone <- function(num){
  v <- num
  while(num > 1L) {
    if(num %% 2L == 1L){
      num <- num*3L + 1L
    }else{
      num = num %/% 2L
    }
    v <- c(v, num)
  }
  v
}    
haillist <- function(num){
  lapply(seq.int(num), hailstone)
}

collatz_seq <- haillist(20)
collatz_seq[[17]][4]
#> [1] 13
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

In the second way, there is only one function to be called, `hailstone`. In this function an anonymous function is called in a `lapply` loop and it's this function that computes the sequences. This function also returns a list.

```r
hailstone <- function(num){
  lapply(seq.int(num), \(n) {
    v <- n
    while(n > 1L) {
      if(n %% 2L == 1L){
        n <- n*3L + 1L
      }else{
        n <- n %/% 2L
      }
      v <- c(v, n)
    }
    v
  })
}

collatz_seq <- hailstone(20)
collatz_seq[[17]][4]
#> [1] 13
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>